# How to have '~/.config/autostart' contents back?

Tags: xubuntu, system

I had to erased all the contents of the folder `/home/rgr/.config/autostart` in the recovery mode in order to start the computer because of a video card change.

Is there a way to have those contents back without having to reinstall all Xubuntu?

Now that I am able to login the windows manager looks not to be working right.

Answer (score 3):

`~/.config/autostart` is empty on a new session (Actually, this directory *doesn't exist* on a new account), and it does not contain any important scripts (i.e. the cause of your WM problem doesn't seems to be there)...

Applications add startup scripts at this location (for instance, dropbox, bzr-notify, remmina-applet, ...) and of course you can add your own... The important autostart scripts (which are not user-dependant) live under `/etc/xdg/autostart`